# Data Formatting for Time Varying Covariate Cox Proportional Hazards Modeling in R

Tags: r, time, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am attempting to develop a time varying Cox proportional hazards (CPH) model in R and was wondering if anyone has generated any code to help format data for the counting structure that is used in time varying / time dependent CPH models.

To make the problem reproducible and somewhat simpler, I have extracted the first 100 rows of data, which features 4 variables (`id`, `date`, `y`, and `x`). The `id` is a unique subject identifier. The `date` is an integer sequence from 0 to n days of observation for each `id`. `y` is the status or outcome of the hazard analysis and `x` is the time varying covariate. In this example, once `y` = 1 has occurred the data for each subject will be censored and no additional data should be included in the ideal output dataframe.

The data are structured so that each subject has 1 row that corresponds to each day of observation.

```
head(test)
id date y x
1     0 0 0
1     1 0 1
1     2 0 1
1     3 0 1
1     4 0 1
1     5 0 0
```

However, as I understand it, the `cph` function in R requires that time varying covariates be structured in such a way that the `start` and `end` variables need to be recoded into 3 rows with intervals from (0,1] and (1,5] and (5,6] for the data featured in the `head(test)` code block above.

The first 100 rows of data can be reconstructed using this code:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9), date = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), x = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"date", "y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ideally, I am trying to recode these data so that the output would be:

```
head(ideal_output)
id start end y x
1      0   1 0 0
1      1   5 0 1
1      5   6 0 0
1      6   7 0 1
1      7   9 0 0
1      9  11 0 1
1     11  20 0 0
2      0   8 0 0
3      0   1 0 0
3      1   3 0 1
3      3   4 0 0
3      4   6 0 1
3      6   7 1 1
4      0   2 0 0
4      2   4 0 1
4      4   7 0 0
5      0   9 0 0
6      0   7 0 0
7      0   1 0 0
7      1   2 0 1
7      2   3 0 0 
7      3   4 1 0
8      0   3 0 0
8      3   4 1 1
9      0   2 0 0
9      2   5 0 1
9      5   6 1 1
```

I have done this manually to create the `ideal_output` above but it is an error prone process and untenable for the hundreds of `id`'s and several covariates that I need to evaluate. Consequently, any help would be greatly appreciated in developing an automated way to approach this data formatting challenge. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the Survsplit() function is the answer to your problem.

look at:
http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eha/functions/SurvSplit

Alternatively, try to google: Chapter 5 Extended and Stratified Cox - nus.edu.sg

Comment: Thanks -- In reviewing these materials I didn't see any mention of how to incorporate 'cuts' based on changes in covariate values (my reading is that the 'cuts' occur based on changes in the event variable only). Do you know if this approach extends to time-changing covariates as well?

Answer (score 1):

As @Ham suggest you can use `tmerge`. Here is an example

```
> #####
> # `dat` is the data.frame you provided 
> library(survival)
> 
> # make baseline data.frame for tmerge
> baseline <- by(dat, dat$id, function(x){
+     n <- nrow(x)
+     # avoid slow data.frame call
+     structure(list(
+       id = x$id[1], start = x$date[1], x = x$x[1], end = x$date[n], 
+       dummy = 0),
+       row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
+   })
> baseline <- do.call(rbind, baseline)
> baseline # show baseline data
  id start x end dummy
1  1     0 0  19     0
2  2     0 0   7     0
3  3     0 0  12     0
4  4     0 0   6     0
5  5     0 0   8     0
6  6     0 0   6     0
7  7     0 0  11     0
8  8     0 0  14     0
9  9     0 0   8     0
> 
> # use tmerge
> final_dat <- tmerge(baseline, baseline, id = id, y = event(end, dummy))
> final_dat <- tmerge(
+   final_dat, dat, id = id, y = cumtdc(date, y), x = tdc(date, x))
> final_dat[final_dat$id == 3, ] # look at one example
   id start x end dummy tstart tstop y
27  3     0 0  12     0      0     1 0
28  3     0 1  12     0      1     2 0
29  3     0 1  12     0      2     3 0
30  3     0 0  12     0      3     4 0
31  3     0 1  12     0      4     5 0
32  3     0 1  12     0      5     6 0
33  3     0 1  12     0      6     7 1
34  3     0 1  12     0      7     8 1
35  3     0 1  12     0      8     9 1
36  3     0 1  12     0      9    10 1
37  3     0 1  12     0     10    11 1
38  3     0 0  12     0     11    12 1
> 
> # remove values where y is not zero or y is not the first non-zero value
> final_dat <- within(final_dat, ycum <- unlist(tapply(y, id, cumsum)))
> final_dat <- final_dat[final_dat$ycum < 2, ]
> final_dat$ycum <- NULL
> final_dat[final_dat$id == 3, ]
   id start x end dummy tstart tstop y
27  3     0 0  12     0      0     1 0
28  3     0 1  12     0      1     2 0
29  3     0 1  12     0      2     3 0
30  3     0 0  12     0      3     4 0
31  3     0 1  12     0      4     5 0
32  3     0 1  12     0      5     6 0
33  3     0 1  12     0      6     7 1
> 
> # remove x row where the previous x value do match. But
> #  * keep those where y = 1
> #  * update tstop for the last row where the last row may be removed
> final_dat <- within(
+   final_dat,
+   max_t <- unlist(tapply(tstop, id, function(z) rep(max(z), length(z))))) 
> final_dat <- within(
+   final_dat, 
+   keep <- unlist(tapply(x, id, function(z)
+     c(TRUE, z[-1] != z[-length(z)]))))
> 
> final_dat <- final_dat[final_dat$keep | final_dat$y, ]
> 
> final_dat <- within(
+   final_dat, is_last <- unlist(tapply(id, id, function(z) 
+     seq_along(z) == length(z))))
> 
> needs_update <- final_dat$is_last & !final_dat$y
> final_dat[needs_update, "tstop"] <- 
+   final_dat[needs_update, "max_t"]  + 1
> 
> # have to update the tstop column 
> final_dat <- within(final_dat, tstop <- unlist(by(
+   cbind(tstart, tstop), id, function(z) {
+     n <- nrow(z)
+     c(z$tstart[-1], z$tstop[n])
+ })))
> 
> # show final data.frame
> final_dat[, c("id", "tstart", "tstop", "y", "x")]
   id tstart tstop y x
1   1      0     1 0 0
2   1      1     5 0 1
6   1      5     6 0 0
7   1      6     7 0 1
8   1      7     9 0 0
10  1      9    11 0 1
12  1     11    20 0 0
20  2      0     8 0 0
27  3      0     1 0 0
28  3      1     3 0 1
30  3      3     4 0 0
31  3      4     6 0 1
33  3      6     7 1 1
39  4      0     2 0 0
41  4      2     4 0 1
43  4      4     7 0 0
45  5      0     9 0 0
53  6      0     7 0 0
59  7      0     1 0 0
60  7      1     2 0 1
61  7      2     3 0 0
62  7      3     4 1 0
70  8      0     3 0 0
73  8      3     4 1 1
84  9      0     2 0 0
86  9      2     5 0 1
89  9      5     6 1 1
```

The code after `tmerge` can be done faster with `dplyr` or `data.table`. If you have more columns than just one, `x`, then I suggest that you: 1) store a column index of `dat` and use that in `tmerge` in the `tdc` function instead of `x`. Then merge the tables afterwards with `merge`. Further, you need to update the line that makes the `keep` indicator. Otherwise the code should be identical.

Comment: Further, two rows like `3      4   6 0 1` and `3      6   7 1 1` are redundant. They could just be `3      4   7 1 1` if you are going to use `coxph`. It will not matter for the results though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tmerge() function is the answer to your problem.

look at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf